# Should psychological checks be as frequent as physical checks to evaluate a patient's condition?

Tags: social-psychology

Are there differences between psychological and physical attributes that could justify the lack of these periodic tests in psychology?

Answer (score 0):

ABSOLUTELY! The physical and mental are often connected. Take, for instance, the Thyriod. If the thyroid is physically unhealthy then it can cause mental disturbances. It can cause a slew of psychological manifestations for someone. When preceived by a psychological professional, they treat the symtoms they interpret and preceive from their paradigm they treat their patient with psychological techniques and medications.

I have seen this first hand where someone can exhibit pyschological disturbances and are incorrectly diagnosed because the psychological professional does not test their physical state.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci and thanks for the answer! However, I think the answer does not really address the question.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. Many often lose sight of the fact that the way in which one perceives the world is subjective. Psychology is a very vauge science and based on mostly theories based on human brains interpreting other human brains. I only worked for one of the major research institutions in the nation for about 2 years working on dissertations for phD students. I was not only the applications/systems developer for their experiments BUT due to the lack of intellectual abilities of the student(s), I also had to educate myself by reading and researching the field of cognitive science

Comment: How do you subjectively perceive this question. What would be an answer that you perceive would be an appropriate answer?

Comment: You really should not have revised the original question because in doing so it completely changed the concept behind the question. Therefore the orignial question no longer exists. 

:)

Comment: A warm welcome from me as well! However, introducing your bio here in the comments to motivate your answer does nothing but causing confusion (and [smells a bit like misuse of appeal to authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority)). The OP agreed that the linked to question is a duplicate, so let's stick with that. If you are interested in sharing your expertise there is nothing preventing you from posting (and answering!) your own question in a new post, the way you interpreted it! Hope to see you around.